# How can i display newest user post in my app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

How can i display newest user post in my app? i have a backend route which display user post but i want that route display latest post of user So how can i do that in my code?

My code:

```
router.get('/postdata', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Find all users in the database
        const users = await User.find();

        // Map over the users array and return an array of objects
        // with the same username, profile_image, and postImage
        const userData = users.flatMap(user => {
            return user.posts.map(post => ({
                username: user.username,
                profile_image: user.profilepic,
                postImage: post.post,
            }));
        });

        return res.json(userData);
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    }
});
```

Comment: Dose user.posts have properties like created_at or updated_at?

Answer (score 1):

If your `posts` model has `created_at` or `updated_at` properties that keep track of when an image was uploaded, you could use that to sort the array in your map.

Let's say your `userData` array has similar output to this.

```
[
  {
    username: 'user1',
    profile_image: 'https://your_domain.com/user1-profile.jpg',
    postImage: 'https://your_domain.com/user1-post1.jpg',
    created_at: '2023-01-01T11:00:00.000

  },
  {
    username: 'user2',
    profile_image: 'https://your_domain.com/user2-profile.jpg',
    postImage: 'https://your_domain.com/user2-post1.jpg',
    created_at: '2023-01-01T12:00:00.000

  }
]
```

Then you can sort the array before rendering it.

```
const sorteduserData = userData.sort((a, b) => {
  return new Date(b.created_at) - new Date(a.created_at);
});
```

It's a good practice to have your backend do the sort to reduce overhead on the front-end and to have your application load faster.

Many of headless CMSs have these features built in.